# Android Studio asking me to download the entire installation all over again

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-sdk-tools

I already have Android Studio 2.2 Beta installed on my computer:

[image]

Updating to Beta 2 should be possible simply by downloading a 12 MB patch as shown on the [Android Tools](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio22beta2) site:

[image]

Instead, when I try to update the IDE, it asks me to download the whole of Beta 2 (~500 MB):

[image]

I already went through this painful process yesterday when updating from 2.1.2 Stable to 2.2 Beta. ***Why*** do I have to go through this again, and is there a way to circumvent it? Anyone else facing the same problem?

Comment: same issue happened with me.... had to download whole setup again

Comment: Current Stable AS is 2.1.3 so download that one. Any reason why you are updating to Beta software?

Comment: You're right, I probably wouldn't be facing this problem with the stable version, but 2.2 has a lot of new features and I wanted to try those!

Comment: I thought that might be the reason :) but to be on the safe side dont install Beta software on you development machine. Use another PC or Visualize one on your Main system to be on the safe side and run it there. If anything goes wrong just delete the VM machine

Comment: I've installed it in a separate location, just as you pointed out, so hopefully it shouldn't be a problem later on ... :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to do what it says. See http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/2-2-beta

> Due to a bug, you can only patch from Android Studio 2.2 Preview 2, 3,
>   4, 5, 6 and 7. **All other versions will need to download a complete
>   install of the IDE.**

This is not the first time this happens in beta/canary channels so if you want bleeding edge versions you most likely will have to use to it. In case of doubts it worth checking http://tools.android.com

Comment: Okay, so I suppose it would be better instead to directly update to **2.2 Stable** whenever it comes out.

Comment: If you just want to try new features, install beta/cannary in separate folder while sticking to Stable for your normal, development setup. This most likely save you some time.